# Iterately read sheets from excel file and modify column names in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

Say I have an excel file `data.xlsx`, which contains multiple sheets: `sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, etc.`

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx')
for sheet in xls.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet)
```

For each sheet, it has same column name: `'ISIN', 'Coupon', 'Issue Date', 'Maturity Date'`.

Now I need to iteratively read all sheets and modify column name `ISIN` with elements of `date_list`，which is `date_list = ['2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', ...]`, then save back as excel file.

The final file's `sheet1`'s column name will be `['2021-01', 'Coupon', 'Issue Date', 'Maturity Date']`, `sheet2`'s will be `['2021-02', 'Coupon', 'Issue Date', 'Maturity Date']`, etc.

How could I do that in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename the dataframe's columns name with `rename` and save the file again.

```py
import pandas as pd
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data_new.xlsx')

for i, sheet_name in enumerate(xlsx.sheet_names):
    df = xlsx.parse(sheet_name)

    # renmae ISIN to '2021-01'...
    df.rename(columns={'ISIN': date_list[i]}, inplace=True)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet) 

writer.save()
```

Comment: It raises a `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`, for `with writer as pd.ExcelWriter('data_new.xlsx'):`.

Comment: ok, I will use `writer.save()` instead of `with`

Comment: my fault, `with pd.ExcelWriter('data_new.xlsx') as writer:` will work

Comment: `NameError: name 'sheet_name' is not defined`, do you forget define `sheet_name`?